# Use PowerShell as the WebStorm terminal and open in current project folder

Tags: powershell, webstorm

I am using WebStorm 2016.1 and have configured PowerShell as the terminal by using `powershell.exe` as the shell path in WebStorm's terminal settings:

[image]

When I open the terminal it does not open in the current project folder, but in my home folder.

[image]

How do I make it open in the current project folder?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Works fine for me. Do you have any PowerShell $PROFILE files? if yes, check if 'Set-Location' is specified there. See also https://superuser.com/questions/507387/autorun-for-powershell

Comment: Thanks...my bad - I had `cd $env:USERPROFILE` in my profile file! :(

Comment: I encountered this issue since I had a command to `Set-Location` to my source code folder in my profile. Upon seeing this solution, I realized a much better pattern is to create a function such as `Open-SourceFolder` which calls `Set-Location` and then alias that with a short code such as `src` (i.e. `New-Alias "src" Open-SourceFolder`). This alleviates the pain of manually navigating in WebStorm and still allows me to quickly navigate to my source code folder externally as well.